# how to subset list base on array in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have following column names in a list:

```
 vars = ['age','balance','day','duration','campaign','pdays','previous','job_admin.','job_blue-collar']
```

I have one array which consists of array indexes

```
(array([1, 5, 7], dtype=int64),)
```

I want to subset the list based on array indexes

Desired output should be

```
vars = ['balance','pdays','job_admin.']
```

I have tried something like this in python

```
for i, a in enumerate(X):
   if i in new_L:
       print i
```

But,it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `numpy` anyway, use its advanced indexing

```
import numpy as np
vars = ['age','balance','day','duration','campaign','pdays',
        'previous','job_admin.','job_blue-collar']
indices = (np.array([1, 5, 7]),)

sub_array = np.asarray(vars)[indices]  
# --> array(['balance', 'pdays', 'job_admin.'], dtype='<U15')
```

or if you want a `list`

```
sub_list = np.asarray(vars)[indices].tolist()
# --> ['balance', 'pdays', 'job_admin.']
```

Answer (score 17):

Simply use a loop to do that:

```
result=[]
for i in your_array:
   result.append(vars[i])
```

or one linear

```
 [vars[i] for i in your_array]
```

Comment: Perfect, without additional library

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your data are:

```
vars = ['age','balance','day','duration','campaign','pdays','previous','job_admin.','job_blue-collar']
```

and indexes are:

```
idx = [1, 5, 7]
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> [vars[i] for i in idx]
['balance', 'pdays', 'job_admin.']
```

Comment: Why do you wrap your list-comprehension in `list`? It's redundant.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Fixed :) Thanks

Comment: fyi, list-comps (`[ ... ]`) are just syntactic sugar for `list()` called on a generator. So it is fine to use `list()` as long as you use a generator inside, not a list comp as otherwise you are calling `list(list())`. However it is more Pythonic to use list-comps

Comment: @JoeIddon Actually that's not entirely true. `x = range(100_000)`

`%timeit list(i for i in x)
7.59 ms ± 120 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

`%timeit [i for i in x]
4.38 ms ± 97.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` List comprensions take advantage of `__len__` and `__length_hint__` where available and so pre-allocate memory making them (slightly) more efficient.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Cool, I guess also Python is optimised so when you use the `list()` function you are adding another call.

Comment: @JoeIddon Maybe, but also since `list` have variable length, knowing (roughly) the length of the new list means it can be immediately assigned that much memory, rather than being dynamically changed on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

```
index = [1, 5, 7]
vars = [vars[i] for i in index]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import operator
>>> vars = ['age','balance','day','duration','campaign','pdays','previous','job_admin.','job_blue-collar']
>>> idx = np.array([1,5,7])
>>> operator.itemgetter(*idx)(vars)
('balance', 'pdays', 'job_admin.'
```

This is actually the fastest solution posted so far.

```
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=1000000)
>>> 
>>> repeat("np.asarray(vars)[idx]", **kwds)
[2.2382465780247003, 2.225632123881951, 2.1969433058984578]
>>> repeat("[vars[i] for i in idx]", **kwds)
[0.9384958958253264, 0.9366465201601386, 0.9373494561295956]
>>> repeat("operator.itemgetter(*idx)(vars)", **kwds)
[0.9045725339092314, 0.9015877249184996, 0.9032398068811744]
```

Interestingly, it becomes more than twice as fast if we convert idx to a list first, and that's including the cost of conversion:

```
>>> repeat("operator.itemgetter(*idx.tolist())(vars)", **kwds)
[0.4062491739168763, 0.4086623480543494, 0.4049343201331794]
```

We can also afford to convert the result to list and still are much faster than all the other solutions:

```
>>> repeat("list(operator.itemgetter(*idx.tolist())(vars))", **kwds)
[0.561687784967944, 0.5593925788998604, 0.5586365279741585]
```